# Number of natural numbers made from the digits 1, 2 and 3 wherein the sum of their digits is equal to n.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

The problem is to count the number of different natural numbers that can be made from three digits 1, 2 and 3 in which the sum of the digits is equal to n.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question is that why you say that the numbers range from 4 to 12 digits? Because the question states that the sum of the digits should be equal to a given constant n.

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a_n$ be the number of such numbers with digit sum $n$. Any number made up of the allowed digits ends with $1$, $2$, or $3$. There are $a_{n-1}$ numbers with digit sum $n$ that end in $1$, $a_{n-2}$ that end in $2$, and $a_{n-3}$ that end in $3$. This gives the recurrence
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}.$$
Using this recurrence, and the initial conditions $a_1=1$, $a_2=2$, and $a_3=4$, we can readily compute $a_n$ for reasonably small $n$.

A closed form can *in principle* be obtained by noting that our recurrence has characteristic polynomial $x^3-x^2-x-1$. We could find the roots $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ of this. They are not pleasant, but can be found explicitly from the Cardano Formula for the roots of the cubic.

Then $a_n=A\alpha^n+B\beta^n+C\gamma^n$ for constants $A,B,C$ determined by the initial conditions.

It so happens that, (apart from where the indexing starts), our sequence is the [Tribonacci Sequence.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers) There is some discussion of the closed form in the linked Wikipedia article. Searching under *tribonacci sequence* will give many more hits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your beautiful solution.

Comment: You are welcome.